error: returning reference to temporary [-Werror=return-local-addr]
I have some code that looks like this
class Interface
{};

class Contained;

class Container
{
public:
    Container() : m_contained(std::make_shared<Contained>(*this))
    {
    }
    
    std::shared_ptr<Interface> get_contained()
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<Interface>(m_contained);
    }
    
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Contained> m_contained;
};

class Contained final : public Interface
{
public:
    Contained(Container& container) : m_container(container)
    {
    }
    
private:
    Container& m_container;
};

I was asked to change get_contained to return a reference, so naively I thought to do
    std::shared_ptr<Interface>& get_contained()
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<Interface>(m_contained);
    }

and compilation failed on

error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::shared_ptr&' to an rvalue of type 'std::shared_ptr'

so I added const
    const std::shared_ptr<Interface>& get_contained()
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<Interface>(m_contained);
    }

and now I fail on

error: returning reference to temporary [-Werror=return-local-addr]

I then tried several more "fixes"
class Container
{
public:
    Container()
    {
        m_contained = std::make_shared<Contained>(*this);
    }

    const std::shared_ptr<Interface>& get_contained()
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<Interface>(m_contained);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Contained> m_contained{};
};

and
class Container
{
public:
    Container()
    {
        m_contained.reset(new Contained(*this));
    }

    const std::shared_ptr<Interface>& get_contained()
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<Interface>(m_contained);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Contained> m_contained{};
};

and in desperation this
class Container
{
public:
    Container()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Contained> ptr = std::make_shared<Contained>(*this);
        m_contained = ptr; // also with std::move, but same result
    }

    const std::shared_ptr<Interface>& get_contained()
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<Interface>(m_contained);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Contained> m_contained{};
};

All failed on the same issue, can't return lvalue reference to temporary.
I don't understand how can a member of a class that is properly initialized be temporary

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast "Creates a new instance of std::shared_ptr..." This new instance is a temporary. Why do you want to return a (const) reference?

Re. "I was asked to change get_contained to return a reference": can I ask why?  What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

I think you misunderstood: "I was asked to change get_contained to return a reference". IMO request was to do: Interface& get_contained() or const Interface& get_contained() const

This is mostly trial and error which is very dangerous in c++(as C++ has UB etc). I would recommend using good c++ book so that you will be able to see that they meant to change the return type to Interface&.

@G.M. conventions and standardization, if I have to name it. Adjusting all API calls to return references instead of some returning by copy, some by raw pointers, and others references

It makes no sense to return a reference to a shared pointer. Either return a shared pointer by value or a reference to the contained object.

I'm pretty sure there was no intention of changing this to Interface& as the returned shared_ptr<Interface> is passed to a constructor of weak_ptr<Interface>

So is the intention to try and prevent the calling code accidentally copying the returned std::shared_ptr and therefore extending its lifetime?  If so, why not just return an std::weak_ptr in the first place?

The question is unclear. What is the expected result? You can't return a reference to a temporary. You can return a reference to m_contained or to *m_contained.

@CforLinux: That "standardization" appears to be instigated by someone who doesn't understand C++ at all. The whole reason that the language gives you the choice is because sometimes you need one option, and sometimes the other. A misguided policy here is actively introducing bugs in your code.

A contained that holds a reference to its container... it smells.

I do not think this can be solved this way, because while the pointer to the derived class is also a pointer to the base class (simplified), the shared_ptr that holds the derived class is in no way connected by inheritance to the shared_ptr that holds the base class.
So there is no way to cast one to the other, and any pseudo-cast actually creates a new copy, which is unfortunately temporary.
If I can suggest anything, the following solution might work:
void get_contained(std::shared_ptr<Interface>& retval)
{
    retval = std::static_pointer_cast<Interface>(m_contained);
}

https://godbolt.org/z/7MoTdxKE6
